# Why does diffraction produce a pattern of light and dark coloured bands? Or, why doesn’t a normal plane/spherical wavefront give a pattern?

Tags: waves, interference, diffraction

I know that diffraction is the changing of a plane wavefront into a spherical wavefront and I understand why it happens (Huygen’s principle), but I don’t get why it gives a pattern of light and dark coloured bands. I don’t get why a diffracted spherical wavefront interferes with itself to give light and dark bands but a normal spherical wavefront, say from a concave lens, or a plane wavefront, doesn’t give them.

1. Take a plane wavefront ||| for example, the light from the bottom of a | is out of phase with the light from the top of the |, but their interference doesn’t give a pattern.
2. Say now that I pass ||| through a slit, the the light from the top of | interferes with the light from below to give a pattern.

Why is there a pattern in the second case and not in the first case ? I can’t visualise it and really understand the interference.

Comment: Diffraction does not always cause bands, example water waves in a single slit diffract uniformly.  Interference is a separate phenomenon, obvious with water waves and 2 slits ... but not so obvious for light ... which shows a pattern for both single and double slits.  Light per Feynman chooses paths based on the EM field.

Comment: @PhysicsDave The misconception is that water waves are like light waves. Water waves need a medium to travel on. Not to mention they need displacement, pressure and gravity to even work. Light waves on the other hand are created by billions of individual coherent photons emitted from the same source. As for a single slit (especially a properly constructive one) The interference pattern is obvious and easy to calculate.

Comment: @Bill the historical misconception is that Huygen's very old (1600s)principle which was always used/invented/developed for matter (water) waves was to used to inappropriately draw conclusions to light.... but the math worked so the rest is history.  Light waves and water waves have a lot in common ..... though the main difference is that we can observe the material medium directly but never the EM field directly.  Also light waves are nodal, like piano strings, they need a starting and ending point to propagate.

Comment: @PhysicsDave You never mentioned the obvious interference from a single slit. Every edge diffracts  photons to create interference patterns when they reach the detection screen.

Comment: @BillAlsept  "for light ... which shows a pattern for both single and double slits." is in  my answer.

Comment: @BillAlsept  Also note that we don't need Huygen's principle at all for double slit interference .... its just simple superposition.

Answer (score 0):

if I am understanding correctly, by out of phase you mean the light that reaches one point from the other is out of phase? Because by definition, a wavefront are contours where a wave has a constant phase.

In the first case I think you may be forgetting the plane is infinitely long. At a point on the wavefront, there are an infinite number of sources superposing in pairs of opposite phases stretching out to +/- infinity. Therefore their contribution cancels and you are just left with the original source point on that wavefront, therefore, there is no difference.

The second case has this diffraction effect because the plane is NOT infinitely long due to the aperture cutting off the edges.

Now, a few extra notes that may or may not improve your overall understanding of waves.

A diffracted wave through a slit does NOT produce a spherical wave, it curves the edges but it does not produce a spherical wave unless the slit is infinitely thin as according to Fraunhofer diffraction.

Think of a point source spherical plane wave - the wavefronts are smooth and there is no diffraction therefore the diffraction cannot be due to the curved gemoetry of the wave.

I hope this helps.

All the best :)

Comment: “Therefore their contribution cancels” How?? That’s exactly what I want to know, how the waves cancel out in the first case

Comment: @Shreya it’s not about the slit, it has to do with diffraction from single edges. One edge creates a unique diffraction pattern and two edges (from a single slit) create a totally different type of pattern when the two single edge patterns overlap. See   billalsept.com

Comment: @Sheya From the Huygen's principle you stated in your question. Each point on the wavefront acts as a source. Imagine an infinite number of point sources all along the wavefront. These sources are going to superpose and intefere with each other - but in the infinite case all of there interference effects cancel out.

Answer (score 0):

Diffraction does not always cause bands, example water waves in a single slit diffract uniformly. Interference is a separate phenomenon, obvious with water waves and 2 slits ... but not so obvious for light ... which shows a pattern for both single and double slits. Light per Feynman chooses paths based on the EM field.

In the dark areas for the DSE there are no photons, they are all in the bright areas.

Comment: The question is about light diffraction. Can you give an example of light diffraction NOT creating an interference pattern (Light and Dark Bands) like the OP describes?

Comment: @BillAlsept No it's really a question about misuse/misunderstanding of Huygen's principle and wavefronts.